# I can't unsort the table

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using ajax jquery, I just wanna find out, how to fix this code.. because my descending ordering isnt working

```
if(isset($_POST["order"])) {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY category ASC ';
}else{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY category DESC ';
}
```

Comment: ___How to fix it___ If you tell us whats wrong with it, we might be able to help

Comment: I already edited my question

Comment: Please show us output from `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @OmegaZero In what specific **way** is it not working? Do you get an error message? Have you tried the resulting `$query` in the database directly?

Comment: The ascending is working but when I tried to descend.. it doesnt work

Comment: It will only add the DESC part IF `$_POST['order']` is not set **Is it set or not set**

Comment: Again, define "doesn't work". Does your query work, but the results don't change? Do the results change, but not the way you expect? Do you get an error message? Have you checked `$query`'s value? Does your computer catch fire and turn into a turtle?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that order contains sorting direction: `$_POST['order']='ASC'` or `$_POST['order']='DESC'` (to be clear) you should simply do:

```
if(isset($_POST["order"])) {
    $order= $_POST['order'];
    $query .= 'ORDER BY category '.$order;
}
```

This way if the order is not defined you will not have any sorting at all in your query, else you will sort in the direction chosen

Comment: Excellent SQL injection. Do not include user input in query strings. Verify that the input is one of two options, and go back to hard-coded query fragments.